# Подключить js файл в другой файл

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-то подключить один js файл в другой?
что-то типа:

```
include 'js_prev.js';
console.log('...');
```

Comment: [По этой ссылке](http://stackoverflow.com/a/950146) ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать такую функцию

```
function include(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

и использовать

```
include('js_prev.js');
```

Другой вариант, это использовать `jQuery.getScript()`. Хорошие примеры есть в  [родной документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Еще можно глянуть в сторону [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) и [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/). Но это более затратные способы, надо будет реорганизовать все скрипты в модульную архитектуру. Реализация последнего из них (CommonJS) положена в основу модулей [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Кроме того, в новый стандарт javascript (ECMAScript 6) добавлена нативная поддержка модулей.